# Pandas: Remove brackets from a list?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

i have a df with lists.I'm trying to remove brackets from a list.

df

```
            a      

    0     ['a','b']
    1     ['a']
    2     ['a','b','c']
    3     []
```

Expected output:

```
            a      

    0     'a','b'
    1     'a'
    2     'a','b','c'
    3
```

Comment: Do you have lists in each cells? If so, you can't remove brackets, unless you turn your data into string type.

Comment: Yes, I do have lists in all cells. I tried converting to string. it was`'a,b'` instead of `'a','b'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['a','b'],
                        ['a'],
                        ['a','b','c'],
                        []]})

df['a'] = ["'"+"', '".join(n)+"'" for n in df['a']]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
               a
0       'a', 'b'
1            'a'
2  'a', 'b', 'c'
3             ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['a'] = ("'"+df['a'].agg("','".join)+"'").replace("''", "")
```

Output:

```
             a
0      'a','b'
1  'a','b','c'
2
```

Comment: its `"'a','b'"` instead of `'a','b'`

Comment: Your output is missing a row.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
m=df['a'].str.len()>0#Boolean select non empty lists
df.loc[m,'a']= ["'"+ item +"'" for item in df.loc[m,'a'].str.join("','") ]#Mask the non empty lists, strip corner bracket and insert inverted commas
df=df.mask(df.applymap(str).eq('[]'))# convert empty list into a a NaN
#df.loc[~m,'a']=''
print(df)



          a
0      'a','b'
1          'a'
2  'a','b','c'
3          NaN
```